# slice string to pieces and store each in new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Help needed. 
I have string like `["wt=WLw","V5=9jCs","7W=71X","rZ=HRP9"]` (unlimited number of pairs)

I need to make an array with pair like `wT` (as index) and `WLw` as value, for the whole string (or simpler `wT` as index0, `WLw` as index 1 and so on)
I'm trying to do it in JavaScript but I just cant figure out how to accomplish this task.

Much much appreciate your help!!

Comment: Your string includes the `[]` outer brackets? If so, start by calling `JSON.parse()` to get an array then `.split()` each element on `=`

Comment: Used JSON.parse() and got array of each char from my string. how can this help?

Comment: What is your _exact original string_ including its outer quotes?  If it includes the `[]`, then `JSON.parse('["wt=WLw", "V5=9jCs", "7W=71X", "rZ=HRP9"]')` returns an array of key=value pairs which can then be `.split()`.

Comment: Tried first with no luck, but copied now and it did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have a string as an index in an array, what you want is an object.

All you need to do is loop over your array, split each value into 2 items (key and value) then add them to an object.

Example:

```
// output is an object
var output = {};
var source = ["wt=WLw","V5=9jCs","7W=71X","rZ=HRP9"];
for (var index = 0; index < source.length; index++) {
    var kvpair = source[index].split("=");
    output[kvpair[0]] = kvpair[1];
}
```

If you wanted an array of arrays, then its much the same process, just pushing each pair to the output object

```
// output is a multidimensional array
var output = [];
var source = ["wt=WLw","V5=9jCs","7W=71X","rZ=HRP9"];
for (var index = 0; index < source.length; index++) {
    output.push(source[index].split("="));
}
```

**Update** If your source is actually a string and not an array then you will have to do a little more splitting to get it to work

```
var output = {};
var sourceText = "[\"wt=WLw\",\"V5=9jCs\",\"7W=71X\",\"rZ=HRP9\"]";
// i have escaped the quotes in the above line purely to make my example work!
var source = sourceText.replace(/[\[\]]/g,"").split(",");
for (var index = 0; index < source.length; index++) {
    var kvpair = source[index].split("=");
    output[kvpair[0]] = kvpair[1];
}
```

**Update 2**

If your desired output is an array of arrays instead of an object containing key-value pairs then you will need to do something like @limelights answer.

Object with Key-Value pairs: `var myObject = { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" };`

with the above code you can access "value1" like this `myObject["key1"]` or `myObject.key1`

Array of Arrays: `var myArray = [ [ "key1", "value1"] ,[ "key2", "value2" ] ];`

with this code, you cannot access the data by "key" (without looping through the whole lot to find it first). in this form both "key1" and "value1" are actually values.

to get "value1" you would do `myArray[0][1]` or you could use an intermediary array to access the pair:

```
var pair = myArray[0];
> pair == ["key1", "value1"]
> pair[0] == "key1"
> pair[1] == "value1"
```

You can use a for each loop on both types of result

```
// array of arrays
var data = [ [ "hello", "world"], ["goodbye", "world"]];

data.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item[0]+" "+item[1]);
});
> Hello World
> Goodbye World

// object (this one might not work very well though)
var data = { "hello": "world", "goodbye": "world" };

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key+" "+data[key]);
});
> Hello World
> Goodbye World
```

Comment: Thing is i want run trough an array using foreach to make manipulations with data.

Comment: In update you added, i cannot put slashes. I getting string like i wrote before.

Comment: can i use ' output = [] ' instead of ' output = {} '?

Comment: @alexela in @NickSlash's solution you get an object, if you want an array `[]` then you have to use the code from my answer. @NickSlash want to update your question with an array based solution aswell?

Comment: @limelights, it'd be the same as yours so no need really :)

Comment: @NickSlash yeah but you deserve the accept, you were first :)

Comment: @alexela I added the slashes in to make my example work, they escape the quotes and will not appear in the output. If your source is a string like that then it will probably already be escaped like my example!

Answer (score 2):

The normal `for loop` would do perfectly here!

```
var list = ["wt=WLw","V5=9jCs","7W=71X","rZ=HRP9"];
var pairs = [];
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
   pairs.push(list[i].split('='));
}
```

This would give you an array of pairs, which I assume you want.
Otherwise just get rid of the outer Array and do `list[i].split('=');`

If you want it put into an object ie. not an Array

```
var pairObject = {};
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    var pair = list[i].split('=');   
    pairObject[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}
```

Comment: I prefer array at this point. but tons of thanks for both variants